# Is query id unique in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift docs state that query id, for example in SVL_STORED_PROC_CALL.QUERY can be used to join system views.

But is it like a sequence or after some iterations query ids will start from 1? For example PID can repeat in the period of 3 days.

Can query id be used in joins when I persist this value in some logging table? Or is it better to use combination of query id, xid, pid, and timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query IDs will recycle.  The timeframe will depend on your cluster's query load.